# Pcie bus error after a fresh ubuntu install

Tags: boot, pcie

I installed Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 on a friends new laptop. It was working fine for sometime and then it started giving this pcie bus error.

### Error : `Pc import:0000e5 pcie bus error:severity corrected,type physical layer,id=00e5(receiver id)`

(this keeps on repeating)

#### laptop:

- Asus x541u
- intel i3 7th gen
- Nvidia geforce 920mx
- 4gb ddr4 ram

#### things i did:

- dual booted it along side windows 10
- normal installation
- installed software from snapcraft and flathub store
- installed on a partition of size 200gb roughly
- wifi worked fine

  #### things I did while trying to fix it (*didn't work*):
- edited `/etc/default/grub` by adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`with

  - pci=nomsi
  - pci=noaer
- updated the graphics drivers to nvidia-driver-390
- reinstalled Ubuntu
- fixing broken packages from ubuntu recovery (it worked only once but started giving the same error from next boot)

### I really don't want him to use windows and I have absolutely no idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you install an Nvidia driver?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue trying a former kernel: vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic